# How do i match list with another list in python

Tags: python, json, string, function

I want to find first list value to another list value in python, where i used `match` and `set` and `findall` other method too but it's not work well in my code.

Here I want to match that `pattern` is in the `longlist` and pattern always startwith.

```
pattern  = ['aaa','bbbb','ccc']
longlist = ['aaa845','bbbbPP44','XXX10','aaa420','ccc1','jjj7000','PPPP'] 

for i in longlist:  # longlist is json data, So this line required. After we can do it any code
  if filter(pattern.match, i): 
    print(i)

  # other tried
  if set(pattern) & set(longlist):
    print(i)
```

Desire output : `aaa845, bbbbPP44, aaa420, ccc1`

Can anyone suggest best coding style without multiple `FOR` loop iteration and fastest performance ?

Comment: do you want the strings in `pattern` to be contained in the string of `longlist` or do you instead what the strings in `longlist` to start with any of the ones in pattern? for the current example both give the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with `any` that short circuits the inner loop if a match is found.

This checks if any of the word in pattern is "contained" in the words of `longlist`.

```
>>> pattern  = ['aaa','bbbb','ccc']
>>> longlist = ['aaa845','bbbbPP44','XXX10','aaa420','ccc1','jjj7000','PPPP']
>>> [i for i in longlist if any(j in i for j in pattern)]
['aaa845', 'bbbbPP44', 'aaa420', 'ccc1']
```

If instead you want the words in `longlist` to "start with" any of the ones in pattern then you need to change the condition like so.

```
>>> [i for i in longlist if any(i.startswith(j) for j in pattern)]
['aaa845', 'bbbbPP44', 'aaa420', 'ccc1']
```

In your given example both happen to yield the same result.

Comment: Still not sure whether OP wants `in` or `startswith` check.